# Django Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError on the server

Tags: python, django

I want to register on my site http://193.124.206.34/accounts/register/

received error

> Request Method:   POST
>   Request URL:    http://193.124.206.34/accounts/register/
>
> Django Version:    2.1.1
>
> Exception Type:    SMTPAuthenticationError
>
> Exception Value:
>   (534, b'5.7.14  Please\n5.7.14 log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 t24sm267392edc.56 - gsmtp')

Registration works correctly on the localhost

What should I do to fix the error?
**What host and port should I use?**
I think that I should change **utilities.py** variable

```
host = "http://localhost:8001"
```

Also, received message from google:

> Warning: Google prevented a suspicious attempt to sign in to your account using your password.

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '193.124.206.34',
    '2a00:f940:2:4:2::fea',
    '193-124-206-34.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru',
    '127.0.0.1',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'vacancy_list.AdvUser'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'alekmosk25@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Alex'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = '****@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
...
```

**models.py**

```
from .utilities import send_activation_notification


user_registrated = Signal(providing_args=['instance'])


def user_registrated_dispatcher(sender, **kwargs):
    send_activation_notification(kwargs['instance'])


user_registrated.connect(user_registrated_dispatcher)
...
```

**utilities.py**

```
signer = Signer()

def send_activation_notification(user):
    if ALLOWED_HOSTS:
        #host = "http://" + ALLOWED_HOSTS[0]
        host = "http://localhost:8001"
    else:
        host = "http://localhost:8001"
    context = {'user': user, 'host': host,
               'sign': signer.sign(user.username)}
    subject = render_to_string('vacancy_list/activation_letter_subject.txt',
                               context)
    body_text = render_to_string('vacancy_list/activation_letter_body.txt', context)
    user.email_user(subject, body_text)
```

**forms.py**

```
class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label="Email")
    password1 = forms.CharField(label="Password1", widget=PasswordInput,
                                help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label="Password2", widget=PasswordInput,
                                help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())

    def clean_password1(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        if password1:
            password_validation.validate_password(password1)
        return password1

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            errors = {'password2': ValidationError('Введённые пароли не совпадают', code='password_mismatch')}
            raise ValidationError(errors)
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.is_active = False
        user.is_activated = False
        if commit:
            user.save()
        user_registrated.send(RegisterUserForm, instance=user)
        return user

    class Meta:
        model = AdvUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'send_messages')
```

**views.py**

```
class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    model = AdvUser
    template_name = 'vacancy_list/register_user.html'
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('register_done')


class RegisterDoneView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "vacancy_list/register_done.html"


def user_activate(request, sign):
    try:
        username = signer.unsign(sign)
    except:
        return render(request, 'vacancy_list/bad_signature.html')
    user = get_object_or_404(AdvUser, username=username)
    if user.is_activated:
        template = 'vacancy_list/user_is_activated.html'
    else:
        template = 'vacancy_list/activation_done.html'
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_activated = True
        user.save()
    return render(request, template)
```

Comment: Please check your variable's value, whether the user and password is correct or not.
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'alekmosk25@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'

Comment: Email and password are correct. I think that problem with host  and port   (at this moment i am using localhost)
I don't know what port and host should i specify

Comment: `EMAIL_HOST` and `EMAIL_PORT` are correct, and `host` isn't the issue here. It's tricky to get Django to send emails using Django. If you search Stack Overflow you'll see many similar problems. I recommend you use a different email provider. One option is to use a transactional mail provider with [django-anymail](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail). If you really want to use gmail, then follow the instructions in the error: `log in via your web browser and then try again`. Then check out https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 and other answers on Stack Overflow.